# ODP.NET Error when trying to open connection (ORA-1153 Encountered)

Tags: odp.net

I have the following code:

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection {ConnectionString = conString};
con.Open();
```

With the following entry in the app.config (actual values removed where #)

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=#myhost#)(PORT=#MyPort#)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=#MyServiceName#));User Id=#UserId#;Password=#Password#; Pooling=false;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

When I hit the `con.Open()` I get the following error:

```
Oracle error ORA-1153 encountered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here ended up being my host name was not fully qualified. I had `servername` and it should have been `servername.domainstuff.domainstuff`

Comment: I am not sure, but I suspect you might get a more meaningful error if you try connecting via (the unmanaged) SQL PLUS or using the unmanaged ODP.NET. That 1153 seems specific to the managed driver.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Googling suggests that your TNS connect string is configured incorrectly. It kind of looks you don't have proper nesting of parenthesis. I would first get this working in a TNSNAMES.ORA file (using an alias in the connect string) to make sure it is valid before trying to put the whole thing into the connect string. Have a look here:

http://csharpdeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/error-ora-1153-using-oracle-manageddataaccess-dll-to-connect/

Comment: I saw this particular post about a dozen times and it didn't help me out.  As my code samples showed above, I had all my parenthesis connected correctly.  What made this task a bit more difficult is that I don't work in an Oracle environment so installing all of that on my box to hit an external to my day to day work didn't seem too prudent.

Comment: Clarence, if you aren't too familiar with Oracle TNS aliases, you might find the EZConnect connect string format easier. It has a connect string like host[:port][/service_name]... for example, sales-server:1521/sales.us.acme.com http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#autoId0